# Angular service variable not updated in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I have the following service:

```
app.service('Cart', function() {
    this.data = [];
    this.addFont = function(font) { return this.data.push(font) };
    this.removeFont = function(i) { return this.data.splice(i, 1); };
    this.count = function() { return this.data.length; };
});
```

And the following directive, that displays a cart icon with the number of items in it:

```
app.directive('cartButton', ['Cart', function(Cart) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<button class="selection"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> {{ Cart.count() }}</button>'
    };
}]);
```

But the counter doesn't work, and there is no error.

**How to access `Cart.count()` inside my directive?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular expressions are evaluated against the scope.

Try to set a function on the scope which will get the count from `Cart`:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<button class="selection"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> {{ getCartCount() }}</button>',
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.getCartCount = function() {
            return Cart.count();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: yes you can also do `$scope.cartCount = Cart.count;`. what's important its that every angular expression in the HTML will be evaluated against a scope.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<button class="selection"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> {{ Cart.count() }}</button>',
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.Cart= Cart;
    }
};
```

You need to assign it to scope.

Comment: As @user3906922 was the first to answer and you provided the same answer, I will accept his, but thank you anyway! That did the trick.